# Cannot Create Bounty - Bug

Tags: support, bounty

I wanted to create a second bounty on the following question:

[Weird Apache Access Logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/602248/weird-apache-access-logs/602648)

But i cannot.

I already have 75+ reputation and any of the criteria wherein a bounty is not allowed is not applicable to my question(shown below):

```
The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a chance to answer your question normally first.

You already have three outstanding bounties. You can only have three open bounties at any one time. To start a bounty on this question, you must award at least one of the previous bounties first.

The question already has a bounty. To start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current bounty to be awarded first.
```

Comment: Exactly what happens when you attempt to start a bounty?

Comment: I don't see an option to create a bounty.

Comment: Possibly-Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234095/can-we-move-start-a-bounty-to-a-more-intuitive-location

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is by design.  You have to double the amount of your previous bounty for subsequent bounties on the same question.  This mechanism is in place to avoid placing multiple cheap bounties on a question in order to maintain high visibility for it.

So, since you already awarded a bounty of 50 rep on that question your next bounty on that question must be at least 100 rep, which you can't give yet.  Get yourself over 100 rep and you should be able to add another bounty.

[**Source**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/75852)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

This question has already had a bounty added (and awarded) ([on this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/604106/32986)).
Questions may not have more than one active bounty - so if you're not seeing the "add bounty" link I think you've found a bug (since the current bounty is awarded you should be able to add a new one).

(I *am* seeing the "add bounty" link -- remember it's *under* the comments)

Comment: (I also think it's a bug that you can't have more than one bounty active - it's especially annoying when I want to put a 500-point bounty on something but it already has a dinky 50 point bounty on it - but that's the way the system currently works.)

Comment: I'm not able to see the link. I think squillman's answer is correct. I'll need atleast 100 reputation to be able to create another bounty. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: @KanishkDudeja Indeed it is! I didn't realize that original bounty was from you :-)

Answer (score -1):

The question has an accepted answer, so there's really no point in giving a bounty. You *can* give away points as an additional bounty to the question if you wish, but answered questions can't be bountied.

Comment: Even if i unaccept the answer, still i don't see an option to create a bounty.